# How to use apply function and lambda to loop through json object in python?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, apply

I have this json object name_lookup like below:

```
[
  {
    "ID": "70B52DA6-F099-4D01-BBD0-03EA97292C26",
    "Name": "Join"
  },
  {
    "ID": "442B1598-20CF-4425-8A28-0438FBF77C46",
    "Name": "Bob"
  }
]
```

My dataframe (df) have structure:

```
Id   Name
     Join
     Bob
```

How can I loop through Json object above and compare name to fill in id in df?

I use this function to load json file:

```
def read_configs(file_name):
    with open(file_name, "r", encoding='utf-8') as read_file:
        lookup = json.load(read_file)
    return lookup
```

Please help me. Many thanks to your help <3

Comment: What you try to compare? just the name, ID?

Comment: Depending on the type of comparison you plan on doing turning your json object into a pandas dataframe might be the simplest solution. See https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming names are unique, it is possible to use `map` function of Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

lookup = [
    {
        "ID": "70B52DA6-F099-4D01-BBD0-03EA97292C26",
        "Name": "Join"
    },
    {
        "ID": "442B1598-20CF-4425-8A28-0438FBF77C46",
        "Name": "Bob"
    }
]

df = pd.DataFrame([[None, "Join"], [None, "Bob"]], columns=["ID", "Name"])

# Convert the list of entities to a dictionary and map names by it
df["ID"] = df["Name"].map({entity["Name"]: entity["ID"] for entity in lookup})
```

Comment: Hi @Elisha, Thanks for your solution but I have this problem: some existed records already have ID so I only want to map the ID for record has null that field, I try to modify your code:

df['ID'] = df['ID'].apply(lambda x: x.map({x: entity["ID"] for entity  in province_lookup}) if pd.isna(x) else x)
But it output error :( How can I do that check?

Comment: It's possible if you mask the relevant rows: 
`df.loc[df["ID"].isnull(), "ID"] = df.loc[df["ID"].isnull(), "Name"].map({entity["Name"]: entity["ID"] for entity in lookup})`

Comment: Hi @Elisha, Many thanks to your help until now <3, Can I ask you one more question T.T If I want to compare not only Name but also Type (which include in json following ID, Name)? Something like this: df.loc[df["ID"].isnull(), "ID"] = df.loc[df["ID"].isnull(), "Name", "Type"].map({entity["Name", "Type"]: entity["ID"] for entity in lookup}) ??? How can i combine condition in this case?